# Is there a way to move a VM built on Win10 to the Hyper-V manager on a 2012 R2 server?

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2

This is for a home lab. I was able to get my hands on a cheap server(PROLIANTDL360P) that had an eval copy of 2012R2 on it. I have Win10 Pro(INSPIRON7786) on my laptop. I have been having a really difficult time finding out if there was a way to move a VM built on my laptop (the were made through quick create in case that changes things) to the server that had the Hyper-V role.

I was having difficulty even connecting to the server because of a CredSSP loop. I made the 2012R2 server a DC and then added my laptop to the domain. That allowed me to connect to the server on the same Hyper-V manager but I'm still unable to move the VM.

[image: win10Manager]

I tried using the export option and moving the Ansible VM data to a shared folder hosted on the R2 as well. While using the import feature it's failing to see the vhd using the wizard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Windows Server 2012 R2 supports VMs in the 5.x configuration version with Gen1 fixed-size VHDs whereas by default your Win10 HV manager will probably be using 9.x with Gen2 dynamic VHDXs. If it's not "seeing" them at all, check to see if it's simply because they are VHDX as "not seeing" in Windows is generally a matter of file extension differences.

## Cost-Benefit Analysis

Yes it can be done, but you won't be able to go back and forth. AFAIK there's no way to do it directly. You have to make a sacrifice.

You have three ways to move them, none of them can be done without changing everything in some way. In practice, generally Linux distros can be rebuilt and individual files copied over as a quick solution. Your next option would be to remake the VMs in WS 2012 with downgraded VHDs, then cloning the file systems over using a disk cloning application. Finally, if you want to do what I think you really want to do, Hyper-V Server 2019 is free, you can host machines to your heart's content and move VMs back and forth at will.

### Rebuilding and moving configs will be the fastest and easiest:

If you want to keep your Windows Server for all its other resources (and GUI!) then this is your best option.

Rebuilding Linux distros for specific purposes is something that you can prepare scripts for and this is a great chance to practice making them.

Create the new machines from scratch and move over any files that you realize are missing once they're installed. If you haven't learned about it yet, [WinSCP makes this a breeze](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php). You can enjoy a handy Windows interface as you search your Linux installs and copy over any files.

### Downgrade your VHDs and insert into new (older-versioned) VMs

1. You create the new VMs with hard drives that are whatever size you want them to end up as on WS 2012.
2. You move those hard drives over to your Win 10 machine.
3. In your Win10 VM Manager, create a new VM without a HD that boots from from a disk cloning ISO (like [Gparted Live](https://gparted.org/livecd.php)). Don't boot yet.

If it were Windows only, we could use [diskpart or dism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/capture-and-apply-windows-using-a-single-wim) but because those are going to be EXT file systems those won't work. If GParted gives you trouble, you could also try an imaging program like [Win32 Disk Imager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) but you might have issues going from GPT to MBR that it can't compensate for as easily. [Aomei Disk Cloner](https://www.ubackup.com/help/disk-clone.html) is another freeware candidate.

4. In your Win10 VM Manager, attach the old and new matching hard drives to that same VM you just made. Now boot it.
5. In the Gparted GUI, clone the original (gen2 VHDX?) hard drive to new (downgraded/gen1 VHD) hard drive.
6. Move the cloned gen1 VHD hard drive back to your WS 2012 machine, make sure that it is set as your primary/only hard drive, make sure that you disabled safe boot (not sure if it qualifies for VMs that old) cross your fingers and pray.

Here are two guides that have similar processes for other people's versions on how to do similar things:

https://www.magrin.one/hyper-v-gen2-to-gen1-vm-conversion.html

https://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-p2v-windows-server-2012-r2-with-uefi-and-a-gpt-disk/

### Move them back and forth without CredSSP issues by upgrading your server for free:

This is the best permanent solution to keep up-to-date with updates and support and cross-compatibility, but will take a while until you figure everything out. If you want to do other things with your Windows Server, skip ahead to the next section.

If all you want is a server to host VMs, you can get the latest and greatest for free from Microsoft's official site:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-hyper-v-server-2019

You'll get a free unlimited license for Windows Hyper-V Server 2019 by just providing some personal information. Although it has no GUI and just a command prompt in a window, once you get used to it (and used to using notepad as your impromptu "GUI"...and get the CredSSP thing figured out) it should be the fastest way to run your dedicated VM server.

***Make sure you remove your laptop from the domain first!***

---

Anyway, whatever you do, it should be a lot of fun!

### A side note:

Accessing another computer's Hyper-V Manager with the CredSSP hoop-jumping when outside a domain is a pain. Adding yourself to the domain just for this purpose adds a bunch of domain gunk to your computer and might lock you out if you're not careful while doing experiments. Additionally, when using the Hyper-V Manager to control the Hypervisor for a remote computer, enough options are missing that it's just not worth it. I suggest (as long as you're using WS 2012) from here on out that you just [connect to the server via Remove Desktop (RDP)](https://www.atlantic.net/vps-hosting/how-to-enable-rdp-windows-server-2012/) and access its GUI that way. If you haven't tried RDP yet, it's GREAT for this.